# Most efficient way to replace all numbers in a string with their doubled equivalent in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, ecmascript-6

For example,

x: `My shop of 23 items came to 54`

turns into

`My shop of 46 items came to 108`

where x is a string

Answer (score 0):

Just use `replace()` with regular expression:

```js
const string = 'My shop of 23 items came to 54';
const doubled = string.replace(/\d+/g, n => n * 2);

// My shop of 46 items came to 108
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom replace function along with a regex to find the items you want to replace, like so:

```js
const string = `My shop of 23 items came to 54`;

const out = string.replace(/\d+/g, function() {
  return parseInt(arguments[0]) * 2;
});

console.log(out);
```